# Is it correct to write size_t num = 0?

Tags: c, integer, unsigned, size-t

I am writing a C program in which I am using `size_t` to store numeric values, As on the internet it says that `size_t` can only store `unsigned` values.

So is it okay to store `0` in it ??

```
size_t num = 0;
```

Comment: Yes, you can even store `-0`

Comment: In what sense are you concerned about 0 not being an unsigned value? That the type of an unadorned integer literal 0 is (signed) `int`? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is fine.

C17 6.7.9 (11):

> The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression, optionally enclosed in braces. The initial value
> of the object is that of the expression (after conversion); **the same type constraints and conversions
> as for simple assignment apply**, taking the type of the scalar to be the unqualified version of its
> declared type.

6.3.1.3 (1) says:

> When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than _Bool , if the value
> can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.

`0` is an expression of type `int` whose value is the number zero.   The value zero can certainly be represented by `size_t`, so that is what it gets initialized to.

You may write `size_t num = 0U;` if you prefer aesthetically to have the signedness match, but its effect is just the same.